# Order discrete x scale by frequency/value

Tags: r, ggplot2, r-faq

I am making a dodged bar chart using ggplot with discrete x scale, the x axis are now arranged in alphabetical order, but I need to rearrange it so that it is ordered by the value of the y-axis (i.e., the tallest bar will be positioned on the left).

I tried order or sort, but result in sort the x-axis, but not the bars respectively.

What have I done wrong?

Answer (score 113, accepted):

Try manually setting the levels of the factor on the x-axis.  For example:

```
library(ggplot2)
# Automatic levels
ggplot(mtcars, aes(factor(cyl))) + geom_bar()
```

[image: ggplot of the cars dataset with factor levels automatically determined]

```
# Manual levels
cyl_table <- table(mtcars$cyl)
cyl_levels <- names(cyl_table)[order(cyl_table)]
mtcars$cyl2 <- factor(mtcars$cyl, levels = cyl_levels)
# Just to be clear, the above line is no different than:
# mtcars$cyl2 <- factor(mtcars$cyl, levels = c("6","4","8"))
# You can manually set the levels in whatever order you please. 
ggplot(mtcars, aes(cyl2)) + geom_bar()
```

[image: ggplot of the cars dataset with factor levels reordered manually]

As James pointed out in his answer, [`reorder`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/stats/topics/reorder.default) is the idiomatic way of reordering factor levels.

```
mtcars$cyl3 <- with(mtcars, reorder(cyl, cyl, function(x) -length(x)))
ggplot(mtcars, aes(cyl3)) + geom_bar()
```

[image: ggplot of the cars dataset with factor levels reordered using the reorder function]

Answer (score 216):

The best way for me was using vector with categories in order I need as `limits` parameter to `scale_x_discrete`. I think it is pretty simple and straightforward solution.

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(factor(cyl))) + 
  geom_bar() + 
  scale_x_discrete(limits=c(8,4,6))
```

[image]

Comment: @HendyIrawan there is no legend unless you've got other dimensions (color, fill) also mapped to the same variable.

Comment: I think this is the best answer. It controls the order of the x-axis values and doesn't transform or affect the data-frame. The use of `factor` and `reorder` changes characteristics of the data, albeit within the `ggplot()` call, and so does more than it need do for the problem at hand.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer !! Why complicate things by writing 2 to 3 lines of code for something you can do in a single elegant (predefined) line of code?

Comment: This also worked for me to order x by value of y:  `scale_x_discrete(limits = DT$x[order(-DT$y)])+`

Comment: If you want to specify the order for all possible levels but don't want unused levels to end up in you plot, check out [my answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66483069/1870254).

Answer (score 46):

You can use `reorder`:

```
qplot(reorder(factor(cyl),factor(cyl),length),data=mtcars,geom="bar")
```

**Edit:**

To have the tallest bar at the left, you have to use a bit of a kludge:

```
qplot(reorder(factor(cyl),factor(cyl),function(x) length(x)*-1),
   data=mtcars,geom="bar")
```

I would expect this to also have negative heights, but it doesn't, so it works!

Comment: I'm shocked this answer doesn't have more upvotes, 90% of the time this is the proper way to do it.

Comment: I think both the factor calls are superfluous. There is an implicit call to factor for the first argument and hte second argument is assumed to be numeric.

Comment: An explanation that helped me figure out what these solutions were doing under the hood: https://rstudio-pubs-static.s3.amazonaws.com/7433_4537ea5073dc4162950abb715f513469.html

Comment: `desc(reorder(.))` can give you the tallest bar on the left.

Answer (score 41):

Hadley has been developing a package called `forcats`. This package makes the task so much easier. You can exploit `fct_infreq()` when you want to change the order of x-axis by the frequency of a factor. In the case of the `mtcars` example in this post, you want to reorder levels of `cyl` by the frequency of each level. The level which appears most frequently stays on the left side. All you need is the `fct_infreq()`.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(forcats)

ggplot(mtcars, aes(fct_infreq(factor(cyl)))) +
geom_bar() +
labs(x = "cyl")
```

If you wanna go the other way around, you can use `fct_rev()` along with `fct_infreq()`.

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(fct_rev(fct_infreq(factor(cyl))))) +
geom_bar() +
labs(x = "cyl")
```

[image]

Comment: This works for `plot_ly` (R plotly) too.

Answer (score 2):

I realize this is old, but maybe this function I created is useful to someone out there:

```
order_axis<-function(data, axis, column)
{
  # for interactivity with ggplot2
  arguments <- as.list(match.call())
  col <- eval(arguments$column, data)
  ax <- eval(arguments$axis, data)

  # evaluated factors
  a<-reorder(with(data, ax), 
             with(data, col))

  #new_data
  df<-cbind.data.frame(data)
  # define new var
  within(df, 
         do.call("<-",list(paste0(as.character(arguments$axis),"_o"), a)))
}
```

Now, with this function you can interactively plot with ggplot2, like this:

```
ggplot(order_axis(df, AXIS_X, COLUMN_Y), 
       aes(x = AXIS_X_o, y = COLUMN_Y)) +
        geom_bar(stat = "identity")
```

As can be seen, the `order_axis` function creates another dataframe with a new column named the same but with a `_o`at the end. This new column has levels in ascending order, so ggplot2 automatically plots in that order.

This is somewhat limited (only works for character or factor and numeric combinations of columns and in ascending order) but I still find it very useful for plotting on the go.

Comment: I guess I don't see the advantage of this compared to just using `reorder` directly. Doesn't `ggplot(df, aes(x = reorder(AXIS_X, COLUMN_Y), y = COLUMN_Y)) + ...` do the same thing, about as concisely, and without the helper function?

Answer (score 1):

[@Yuriy Petrovskiy's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7464821/1870254) is great if you know the levels you want to plot beforehand. If you don't (e.g. because you don't want to plot levels not present in the data), consider using a *`limit` function* instead to specify the order:

```r
library(ggplot2)

my_order <- as.character(c(8,3,4,5,6))    # the `as.character` calls are only
ggplot(mtcars, aes(as.character(cyl))) +  # necessary for the OP's example
  geom_bar() +
  scale_x_discrete(limits = function(x) intersect(my_order, x))
```

[image]

From the documentation of `scale_x_discrete`:

> `limits` 
>       One of: 
>       -  NULL to use the default scale values
>       - A character vector that defines possible values of the scale and their order
>       **- A function that accepts the existing (automatic) values and returns new ones**

Otherwise your graph would end up like this (might be preferable):

```r
ggplot(mtcars, aes(as.character(cyl))) +
  geom_bar() +
  scale_x_discrete(limits = my_order)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to manually set the order along the x-axis using `fct_relevel` from `forcats` (part of `tidyverse`). However, for arranging by frequency, @jazzurro provides the best answer by using `fct_infreq` (also from `forcats`).

```
library(tidyverse)

ggplot(iris, aes(
  x = fct_relevel(Species, 'virginica', 'versicolor', 'setosa'),
  y = Petal.Width)) +
  geom_col() +
  xlab("Species") +
  ylab("Petal Width") +
  theme_bw()
```

Output

[image]

Further, the variable needs to be a factor before using `fct_relevel` inside `ggplot`. So, just apply `factor` to the variable first, then use `fct_relevel`.

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(fct_relevel(factor(cyl), "6", "8", "4"))) +
  geom_bar() +
  labs(x = "cyl")
```

Output

[image]