# Arranging subgroups in ggplot

Tags: r, rstudio

I have this set of data

```
data<-read.table("http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=Vb8S91LX", header=TRUE)
```

When i plot them using `ggplot`, the X axis subgroup is automatically arranged as `GS`, `i_GS` and `Nor` for each x variable.

the code i use is

```
ggplot(data, aes(x=gene, y=value,fill=as.factor(group))) + 
   geom_bar(stat='identity', position='dodge') +
   geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=value, ymax=value+std),position=position_dodge(0.9), width=.2) +
   scale_fill_grey() +
   theme_bw() + 
   xlab("gene symbol")+
   ylab("value") + 
   theme(text = element_text(size=20, face="bold"),
   axis.text.x = element_text(vjust=2))
```

My question:
 How could i reverse them "i mean the subgroup not the X axis" so that i could get them as `Nor`, `i_GS`, `GS`?

**Data**

```
data <- structure(list(gene = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 
8L, 9L, 10L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 1L, 2L, 
3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L), .Label = c("C3", "C4A", "C4B", 
"C5", "C6", "C7", "C8A", "C8B", "C8G", "C9"), class = "factor"), 
    group = structure(c(3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("GS", "i_GS", "Nor"), class = "factor"), 
    value = c(149L, 43L, 19L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 15L, 192L, 
    68L, 67L, 51L, 14L, 13L, 0L, 9L, 7L, 41L, 407L, 70L, 71L, 
    170L, 45L, 47L, 19L, 43L, 24L, 125L), std = c(26L, 17L, 33L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 51L, 3L, 5L, 45L, 12L, 11L, 0L, 
    8L, 6L, 29L, 73L, 6L, 6L, 84L, 16L, 30L, 17L, 30L, 10L, 2L
    )), .Names = c("gene", "group", "value", "std"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-30L))
```

Comment: This sound like you need to define the levels of your `group` variable see`?factor`, otherwise they are plot in alphabetical order . Have a search on SO about changing the order of variables in ggplot- there are lots of examples

Comment: Change the `factor` level of group `data$group <- factor(data$group, levels=c("Nor", "i_GS", "GS"))` and then change `fill=group` in your `ggplot` call

Comment: actually this is a better dup: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3253641/how-to-change-the-order-of-a-discrete-x-scale-in-ggplot

Comment: user20650  yep, i saw that one before posting. as i noted in the post i would like to sort the subgroup not the x axis itself,, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add this before ggplot():

```
data$group <- factor(data$group, levels = c("Nor", "i_GS", "GS"))
```

Idea is that ggplot reads from factors the way they are arranged in data frame. Hence you have to rearrange the factor in the data frame if you want to see them visualized differently.

Comment: A. Val ,,, Unfortunately, adding scale_x_discrete(limits = c("Nor", "i_GS", "GS")) does not work

Comment: Well, it was a wild shot before I had a chance to see your code.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: @Werner; but this is a solution - what am i missing thanks?

Comment: @A.Val. ; ggplot arranges in alphabetical order, i think, rather than the order they are found in the dataframe

Comment: @A.Val , ggplot arranged subgroups different than shown in the data frame . However, setting the levels before plotting did reversed the graph as i need. Thanks !