# How to plot multiple columns in R for the same X-Axis Value

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

I need to plot three values, to make three bars for each value of the X-Axis. My data is:
[image: My dataframe DF]

In the X-Axis must be the column labeled as "m" and for each "m" value I need to plot the correspondent "x","y" and "z" value.

I want to use ggplot2 and I need something like this:

[image: Goal]

Comment: Can you provide some reproducible data to demonstrate what you want to accomplish?

Comment: Please include a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input data and show any code you've written so far.

Comment: Sorry, it was not uploaded at first, I got some problems with the pics

Comment: It's not helpful to post pictures of data. Better to share data with a dput(). See the link I provided for better suggestions for including data I your question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I created my own dataset to demonstrate how to do it:

Data:

```
x <- runif(12,1,1.5)
y <- runif(12,1,1.5)
z <- runif(12,1,1.5)
m <- letters[1:12]
df <- data.frame(x,y,z,m)
```

Solution:

```
#first of all you need to melt your data.frame
library(reshape2)
#when you melt essentially you create only one column with the value
#and one column with the variable i.e. your x,y,z 
df <- melt(df, id.vars='m')

#ggplot it. x axis will be m, y will be the value and fill will be
#essentially your x,y,z
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(df, aes(x=m, y=value, fill=variable)) + geom_bar(stat='identity')
```

Output:

[image]

If you want the bars one next to the other you need to specify the `dodge` position at `geom_bar` i.e.:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x=m, y=value, fill=variable)) + 
       geom_bar(stat='identity', position='dodge')
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you really really much, your solution has saved me.

Do you know how to avoid the X-Axis values to appear alphabetically sorted?

Comment: You are welcome :) Glad I could be of help. There is a very good answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3253641/how-to-change-the-order-of-a-discrete-x-scale-in-ggplot) about changing the order (the second answer, not the accepted one). You need to use `scale_x_discrete` with the `limits` argument.