# ggplot2 geom_bar - how to keep order of data.frame

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-bar

I have a question concerning the order of data in my `geom_bar`.

This is my dataset:

```
  SM_P,Spotted melanosis on palm,16.2
  DM_P,Diffuse melanosis on palm,78.6
  SM_T,Spotted melanosis on trunk,57.3
  DM_T,Diffuse melanosis on trunk,20.6
  LEU_M,Leuco melanosis,17
  WB_M,Whole body melanosis,8.4
  SK_P,Spotted keratosis on palm,35.4
  DK_P,Diffuse keratosis on palm,23.5
  SK_S,Spotted keratosis on sole,66
  DK_S,Diffuse keratosis on sole,52.8
  CH_BRON,Dorsal keratosis,39
  LIV_EN,Chronic bronchities,6
  DOR,Liver enlargement,2.4
  CARCI,Carcinoma,1
```

I assign the following colnames:

```
  colnames(df) <- c("abbr", "derma", "prevalence") # Assign row and column names
```

Then I plot:

```
  ggplot(data=df, aes(x=derma, y=prevalence)) + geom_bar(stat="identity") + coord_flip()
```

[image: Plot]

Why does ggplot2 randomly change the order of my data. I would like to have the order of my data in align with my `data.frame`.

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: It's not random, it's alphabetical. See here for solution http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3253641/change-the-order-of-a-discrete-x-scale

Comment: First of all thanks for your response.

If I apply `derma_table <- table(df$derma)
derma_levels <- names(derma_table)[order(df$prevalence)]
df$derma2 <- factor(df$derma, levels =derma_levels)` and then plot `ggplot(data=df, aes(x=derma, y=prevalence)) + geom_bar(stat="identity") + coord_flip()` plots exactly the same as in my question. In fact the commands only change the data.frame into alphabetical order which is exactly what I would like to avoid`

Comment: you are re-leveling the `derma2` factor, but then using `x=derma`

Comment: Hey arvi, first of all thanks for your patience. I don't fully understand because if I open my `df` df$derma and df$derma2 have exactly the same order anyway. So if I change what df$ I plot it doesn't make a difference.

Comment: See below for plot ordering either by 'native order' or sorted by prevalence

Comment: The order of rows in your data frame doesn't matter at all. The order that matters is the order of the levels of the factor: `levels(df$derma)`. You put those in whatever order you want to plot.

Comment: @jaap I think this question (i.e. how to stop reordering of cols) is slightly (but importantly) different to the question how to reorder cols. I think it would be very useful to reopen on that basis. The reason being, if an order has been determined earlier in a workflow, the current best answers make this happen: i) order determined, ii) ggplot reorders, iii) (best answers) reorder again. Which doesn't make much sense if the data were originally in the correct order and some (any) way exists to stop geom_bar from reordering

Answer (score 64, accepted):

Posting as answer because comment thread getting long. You have to specify the order by using the factor levels of the variable you map with `aes(x=...)`

```
# lock in factor level order
df$derma <- factor(df$derma, levels = df$derma)

# plot
ggplot(data=df, aes(x=derma, y=prevalence)) + 
    geom_bar(stat="identity") + coord_flip()
```

Result, same order as in `df`:
[image]

```
# or, order by prevalence:
df$derma <- factor(df$derma, levels = df$derma[order(df$prevalence)])
```

Same plot command gives:

[image]

---

I read in the data like this:

```
read.table(text=
"SM_P,Spotted melanosis on palm,16.2
DM_P,Diffuse melanosis on palm,78.6
SM_T,Spotted melanosis on trunk,57.3
DM_T,Diffuse melanosis on trunk,20.6
LEU_M,Leuco melanosis,17
WB_M,Whole body melanosis,8.4
SK_P,Spotted keratosis on palm,35.4
DK_P,Diffuse keratosis on palm,23.5
SK_S,Spotted keratosis on sole,66
DK_S,Diffuse keratosis on sole,52.8
CH_BRON,Dorsal keratosis,39
LIV_EN,Chronic bronchities,6
DOR,Liver enlargement,2.4
CARCI,Carcinoma,1", header=F, sep=',')
colnames(df) <- c("abbr", "derma", "prevalence") # Assign row and column names
```

Comment: Thanks for your effort! I really appreciate your help! Did you remove some lines from the code which you posted? I don't get the same tick marks when I try the code.

Comment: the only thing I didn't post was the code I used to read in your data. now added.

Comment: Strange ... I get a different axis. Anyway, thank you very much for your effort! Much appreciated! :)

Comment: If anyone is wondering how to do this with data where levels are present more than once in the variable (i.e., when _not_ using `stat = "identity"` but rather the default count stat), you can add the `unique()` function in the first step. For example: `df$var <- factor(df$var, levels = unique(df$var))`

Comment: @stragu if you are not using `unique()` in the newer versions of R, you may encounter problems. Thanks for that tip