# Force geom_bar to not interfer with x ordering under any circumstances?

Tags: r, ggplot2, tidyverse, geom-bar

I am trying to disable the alphabetical reordering of the x variable in a `geom_bar`. I see lots of questions and answers around how to *reorder* the x variable in a simple bar chart (e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25664007/reorder-bars-in-geom-bar-ggplot2), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38131596/ggplot2-geom-bar-how-to-keep-order-of-data-frame), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5208679/order-bars-in-ggplot2-bar-graph)), but each of the answers introduces complexity which is not necessary if the order can be **left in tact**

Is there ***any*** way to pipe a pre-arranged data.frame to a `geom_bar()` and have the alphabetical reordering deactivated so that the resulting bar chart simply displays `x` in the order that x appears in the data.frame?

#### Example

Suppose we have some data that is already ordered the way it should be plotted

```
df <- structure(list(software = c("Python", "R", "SQL", "Hadoop", "Tableau", 
                                  "Scala", "SAS", "Java", "C", "Spark"), users = c(6440, 5750, 4725,1755, 1660, 1560, 1490, 965, 875, 830)), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = "data.frame")


#   software users
# 1    Python  6440
# 2         R  5750
# 3       SQL  4725
# 4    Hadoop  1755
# 5   Tableau  1660
# 6     Scala  1560
# 7       SAS  1490
# 8      Java   965
# 9         C   875
# 10    Spark   830



df %>% ggplot(aes(software, users)) + geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1))
```

This reorders `x` - how can we force the `geom_bar` to ***not*** reorder the columns alphabetically so that the resulting bar chart displays `x` in the order in which it appears in the data.frame, and so that we do not have to do any further reordering?

Answer (score 4):

Change it to factor and arrange them based on the occurrence.

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

df %>% 
  mutate(software = factor(software, levels = unique(software))) %>%
  ggplot() + aes(software, users) + geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1))
```

[image]

To rearrange without changing the column to factors, we can use `reorder`

```
ggplot(df) + aes(reorder(software, match(software,unique(software))), users) + 
geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1))
```

Comment: Is there any way of doing this without changing the input data.frame? (e.g. without changing to a factor?)

Answer (score 4):

Alternatively, jou can also simply set the limits of the x axis, which saves you from fumbling with factors:

```
df %>% ggplot(aes(software, users)) + 
    geom_col() + 
    scale_x_discrete(limits = unique(df$software))
    theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1))
```

Friendly reminder: `geom_col()` is the same as `geom_bar(stat = "identity")`, but shorter.