# Why does the order of my tooltips change when using ggplotly?

Tags: r, ggplot2, plotly, ggplotly

When I add my own text into the tooltips for ggplotly the order of the text changes. In my example the order is Portuegese then German in my text, however on the plot the order is different.

How do I fix this?

Thanks

```
library(ggplot2);
library(plotly);

language <- c("de","es","hi","pt","sv","en")
averageRating <- c(6,4,3,9,10,30)
my_data <- data.frame(language, averageRating)
text <- c("Portuegese","German","Spanish","Hindi","Swedish","English")
p <- ggplot(data=my_data, aes(x=language, y=averageRating, text = text)) +
geom_bar(stat = "identity")

ggplotly(p, tooltip = c("text"))
```

Comment: Do you need this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38131596/ggplot2-geom-bar-how-to-keep-order-of-data-frame

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should try `factor` within `aes` when applying `ggplot`, e.g.,

```
ggplot(data = my_data, aes(x = factor(language, levels = language), y = averageRating, text = text))
```

Answer (score 0):

To fix this I added a new column in my dataframe with the name I wanted displayed in the tooltip. I then set the "text" inside the aesthetic to that column name.

```
library(ggplot2);
library(plotly);
my_data <- read.csv("languageVsRating.csv")
p <- ggplot(data=my_data, aes(x=reorder(language,-averageRating), y=averageRating, text = fullName)) +
geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
labs(x="Film Language",y="Average Rating")+
geom_hline(aes(yintercept = 6.9,linetype="Mean"),colour='red',size=1)+
geom_hline(aes(yintercept = 6.7,linetype="Median"),colour='blue',size=1)+
scale_linetype_manual(name = "",values = c(2,2),guide = guide_legend(override.aes = list(color = c("red", "blue"))))

ggplotly(p, tooltip = c("text","y"))
```

There is another column inside languageVsRating.csv with the language full name