# Order bar graph by value ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart

My df:

```
summary2

Source: local data frame [4 x 2]

      mean      Patch
     (dbl)     (fctr)
1 3.210293   Scotland
2 3.555884         UK
3 3.883458   UK North
4 4.003116 Department
```

The df is already ordered by mean but when I draw bar plot, it messes up the order.

Here is the code:

```
    ggplot(summary2,aes(x=Patch,y=mean, fill = Patch)) +
  geom_bar(colour="black",stat = "identity")
```

Any ideas how to put it in ordered bar graph?

Comment: you need to have the levels of the factor in the order you want them - you can use `reorder` to do this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solution that's completely inspired by [this post:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3253641/change-the-order-of-a-discrete-x-scale)

```
df = read.table(header = TRUE, 
text = 'mean      Patch
1 3.210293   Scotland
2 3.555884         UK
3 3.883458   UKNorth
4 4.003116 Department')

ggplot(df,aes(x=Patch,y=mean, fill = Patch)) +
  geom_bar(colour="black",stat = "identity") + 
  scale_x_discrete(limits = df$Patch[order(df$mean)])
```

There are also other solutions mentioned via reordering.