# Setting order of scale_x_discrete when there are repeated levels

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to make usual geom_point plot using ggplot. But some of x values are repeated and I want to repeat them again in the x axis. So I tried `scale_x_discrete` and followed the example at here [change-the-order-of-a-discrete-x-scale](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3253641/change-the-order-of-a-discrete-x-scale) but I was not able to do what I want.

Here is my example

```
x = c(seq(1,4),seq(2,4))
y= (seq(1,7))
ex=rep(c("ex1","ex2"),c(4,3))

df <- data.frame(x,y,ex)
x y  ex
1 1 1 ex1
2 2 2 ex1
3 3 3 ex1
4 4 4 ex1
5 2 5 ex2
6 3 6 ex2
7 4 7 ex2

ggplot(df, aes(x=factor(x),y=y)) + 
  geom_point(size=4) + 
  scale_x_discrete(limits=c(seq(1,4),seq(2,4)))
```

[image]

with discrete x repeat values, the repeated x axis values is not shown. How can repeat `2,3,4` values again after `1,2,3,4` in the x axis?

Thanks

Comment: Unclear. What order for ties? Why use numeric class data. This must be factor data if these items are distinct.

Comment: @42 because x axis is numeric. I thought `scale_x_discrete` will do the trick but it is not working for repeated factor levels.

Comment: @ think you have made an experiment and repeated some values again and finally you want to see all your data in the same graph.

Comment: So. Add a data example that reflects the order of the experiments.

Comment: @42- I added `ex` value to df which reflects the order of the experiments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you want not `x` but a combination of repeat and `x` as x-axis, it is a natural idea to give `aes(x)` the combination.

```
ggplot(df, aes(x = interaction(x, ex), y = y)) + 
  geom_point(size=4)  +
  scale_x_discrete(labels = df$x)
```

[image]