# Ordering alphanumeric variables for plotting

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr

How to I order a set of variable names along the x-axis that contain letters and numbers? So these come from a survey where the variables are formatted like `var1`, below. But when plotted, they appear `out_1`, `out_10`, `out_11`...

But what I would like is for it to be plotted `out_1`, `out_2`...

```
library(tidyverse)
var1<-rep(paste0('out','_', seq(1,12,1)), 100)
var2<-rnorm(n=length(var1) ,mean=2)
df<-data.frame(var1, var2)
ggplot(df, aes(x=var1, y=var2))+geom_boxplot()
```

I tried this:

```
df %>% 
separate(var1, into=c('A', 'B'), sep='_') %>% 
arrange(B) %>%  
ggplot(., aes(x=B, y=var2))+geom_boxplot()
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/3253641/3358272

Comment: That is, `ggplot2` is honoring the order of the levels within the factor `df$var1`. You have complete control over that, with `factor(..., levels=)` or `levels(...)<-`.

Answer (score 2):

You can order the levels of `var1` before plotting:

```
levels(df$var1) <- unique(df$var1)
ggplot(df, aes(var1,var2)) + geom_boxplot()
```

Or you can specify the order in ggplot scale options:

```
ggplot(df, aes(var1,var2)) +
  geom_boxplot() +
  scale_x_discrete(labels = unique(df$var1))
```

Both cases will give the same result:

[image]

You can also use it to give personalized labels; there's no need to create a new variable:

```
ggplot(df, aes(var1, var2)) +
  geom_boxplot() +
  scale_x_discrete('output', labels = gsub('out_', '', unique(df$var1)))
```

[image]

Check `?discrete_scale` for details. You can use `breaks` and `labels` in different combinations, including the use of labels that came from outside your data.frame:

```
pers.labels <- paste('Output', 1:12)

ggplot(df, aes(var1, var2)) +
  geom_boxplot() +
  scale_x_discrete(NULL, labels = pers.labels)
```

[image]

Comment: This is better than mine. I'm not sure what I was thinking :)

Comment: I should have made it clear; I need the labels to follow the order of another variable. I will change the code.

Comment: You don't need to create a new variable if it's just to personalize the labels. Just set what you want with the options `breaks` and `labels` inside scale_x. See `?discrete_scale` for details.