# R - Ordering factors by another variable returns NAs: How to fix?

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr

I have a small `tibble` of `animal_observations` in R like this:

```
> animal_observations
# A tibble: 12 x 3
   SPECIES       n_detections detection_rate
   <fct>                <int>          <dbl>
 1 Badger                 203          0.190
 2 Blackbird              463          0.433
 3 Domestic cat           292          0.273
 4 Grey squirrel          788          0.736
 5 Hedgehog               179          0.167
 6 Nothing                960          0.897
 7 Pheasant               476          0.445
 8 Rabbit                 602          0.563
 9 Red fox                424          0.396
10 Roe Deer               621          0.580
11 Small rodent           198          0.185
12 Woodpigeon             381          0.356
```

Where `n_detections` is the number of times I've seen that animal, and `detection_rate` is how often that `SPECIES` of animal is seen (calculated elsewhere).

Here's the `dput()`:

```
structure(list(SPECIES = structure(1:12, .Label = c("Badger", 
"Blackbird", "Domestic cat", "Grey squirrel", "Hedgehog", "Nothing", 
"Pheasant", "Rabbit", "Red fox", "Roe Deer", "Small rodent", 
"Woodpigeon"), class = "factor"), n_detections = c(203L, 463L, 
292L, 788L, 179L, 960L, 476L, 602L, 424L, 621L, 198L, 381L), 
    detection_rate = c(0.189719626168224, 0.432710280373832, 
    0.272897196261682, 0.736448598130841, 0.167289719626168, 
    0.897196261682243, 0.444859813084112, 0.562616822429907, 
    0.396261682242991, 0.580373831775701, 0.185046728971963, 
    0.35607476635514)), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
), row.names = c(NA, -12L))
```

I want to order my animals (`SPECIES`, which is a factor) by the `detection_rate` for downstream `ggplot()`ing (e.g. `geom_col()` where `aes(x = SPECIES, y = detection_rate)` and the columns will be ordered by `detection_rate`), etc., and here is the line I tried to run:

```
animal_observations$SPECIES <- factor(animal_observations$SPECIES,
                      levels = animal_observations[order(animal_observations$detection_rate, decreasing = F), "SPECIES"])
```

Strangely, here is the resulting `tibble`:

```
> animal_observations
# A tibble: 12 x 3
   SPECIES n_detections detection_rate
   <fct>          <int>          <dbl>
 1 NA               203          0.190
 2 NA               463          0.433
 3 NA               292          0.273
 4 NA               788          0.736
 5 NA               179          0.167
 6 NA               960          0.897
 7 NA               476          0.445
 8 NA               602          0.563
 9 NA               424          0.396
10 NA               621          0.580
11 NA               198          0.185
12 NA               381          0.356
```

As you can see all of the `SPECIES` have become NAs... What did I do wrong and how do I correct it so that the `SPECIES` factor is ordered ("levelled"?) by `detection_rate` so that in the output `tibble` all the animal names are retained in the `SPECIES` column? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `reorder()` inside `ggplot()`:

```
animal_observations %>% 
  ggplot(aes(reorder(SPECIES, detection_rate), detection_rate)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity") + 
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle=90))
```

[image: plot]

**UPDATE**
To set the new order before getting into `ggplot()`, use `mutate` and `order` the existing factor to set a new one:

```
animal_observations %>% 
  mutate(species = factor(SPECIES, levels=SPECIES[order(detection_rate)])) %>%
  ggplot(aes(species, detection_rate)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity") + 
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle=90))
```

Comment: Thank you so much, it worked for me, too! That said, is there a way to do this directly to `animal_observations` rather than within `ggplot` (this way the order/levels will apply to other potential operations as well)?

Comment: Yes it worked, thank you so much! It's great to know *both* ways of doing it which provides flexibility.

Answer (score 1):

It's this simple

```
library(dplyr)
animal_observations %>% arrange(desc(detection_rate))
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick response, but after doing this then using `geom_col()` to plot `detection_rate` as a function of `SPECIES`, the plot is *not* ordered by `detection_rate`, it is still ordered by `SPECIES`. How do I define the levels of the factor `SPECIES` so that the plot *will* be ordered by `detection_rate`?

Comment: @hpy you may find [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3253641/change-the-order-of-a-discrete-x-scale) useful

Answer (score 1):

Another option would be using `order` like this

```
# df = your dput()
with(df, df[order(detection_rate, decreasing = TRUE),])
```

and the output

```
# A tibble: 12 x 3
   SPECIES       n_detections detection_rate
   <fct>                <int>          <dbl>
 1 Nothing                960          0.897
 2 Grey squirrel          788          0.736
 3 Roe Deer               621          0.580
 4 Rabbit                 602          0.563
 5 Pheasant               476          0.445
 6 Blackbird              463          0.433
 7 Red fox                424          0.396
 8 Woodpigeon             381          0.356
 9 Domestic cat           292          0.273
10 Badger                 203          0.190
11 Small rodent           198          0.185
12 Hedgehog               179          0.167
```

Comment: Thanks! But similar to after trying the other answer, I then tried using `geom_col()` to plot `detection_rate` as a function of `SPECIES`, the plot is *not* ordered by `detection_rate`, it is still ordered by `SPECIES`. How do I define the levels of the factor `SPECIES` so that the plot *will* be ordered by `detection_rate`?