# R lollipop with conditional segment coloring

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a csv file that I reduce to 3 columns and place in a data frame. The data is a date, a number, and a hex color code in that order. I would like to make a horizontal lollipop chart and have been following

*Edit to add sample data in the code section

https://www.r-graph-gallery.com/301-custom-lollipop-chart/

Everything works fine until I want set the segment colors by calling the color column. Then it loses the sorting for the color.

I don't quite grasp the mutate function so I'm guessing it's happening there. If someone could explain what's happening there, that would also be appreciated.

```
library(tidyverse)
dir <- 'C:[file directory]'
setwd(dir)
file <- "KK3s.csv"
mydata <- read.csv(file, header=T, as.is=T)

#sample data
Match UP ,W/L,MIN,PTS,FGM,FGA,FG%,3PM,3PA,3P%,FTM,FTA,FT%,OREB,DREB,REB,AST,STL,BLK,TOV,PF,+/-
    28-Feb-19,W,22,22,8,15,53.3,6,10,60,0,0,0,0,3,3,2,1,0,2,2,9
    27-Feb-19,W,12,0,0,2,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,-6
    23-Feb-19,W,15,7,1,7,14.3,1,6,16.7,4,4,100,0,4,4,1,0,0,1,1,1
    22-Feb-19,L,11,6,2,5,40,2,4,50,0,0,0,0,2,2,1,0,1,2,0,1
    12-Feb-19,L,19,5,1,3,33.3,0,2,0,3,3,100,0,4,4,3,1,0,2,1,0
    9-Feb-19,W,22,5,2,4,50,1,3,33.3,0,0,0,0,3,3,0,1,0,0,1,5
    6-Feb-19,W,15,3,1,5,20,1,4,25,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,2
    2-Feb-19,L,17,8,3,6,50,1,3,33.3,1,3,33.3,0,2,2,1,0,0,2,1,3    

#add color column with a baseline color
mydata$color <- rgb(249, 161, 26, maxColorValue=255)
#change color based on W or L 
mydata$color[mydata$W.L<"W"] = rgb(43, 81, 52, maxColorValue=255)

#Reduce df to only necessary columns
data <- data.frame(x=mydata$Match.Up, y=mydata$X3PM, WLcolor =  mydata$color)

data %>%
  arrange(y) %>%
  mutate(x=factor(x,x)) %>%
  ggplot( aes(x=x, y=y)) +
    geom_segment( aes(x=x, xend=x, y=0, yend=y), 
      color = data$WLcolor,
      size=1) +
    geom_point( color="blue", size=4, alpha=0.6) +
    theme_light() +
    coord_flip() +
    theme(
      panel.grid.major.y = element_blank(),
      panel.border = element_blank(),
      axis.ticks.y = element_blank()
    ) +
    xlab("Date") +
    ylab("3PM")
```

[Output from my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2DpNZ.png)

Any data that has 3PM > 3 should have yellow lines

Comment: It's hard to help without a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)--we don't have a sample of your data, or the output you got, and it's unclear what you mean by "it loses the sorting for the color," so we don't know what you're looking at or what you're trying to get

Comment: But without any of that information, I'd guess it's one of two classics: [ordering a variable](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3253641/5325862) or [using `$` inside `aes`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32543340/5325862) (you shouldn't)

Comment: Added sample data and an image of my output

Comment: And I'll take a look at those two examples you linked to. Thank you very much!