# reorder currency x-axis in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am quite new in ggplot and I have a question to relabelling the x-axis.

```
ggplot(female_income)+geom_bar(mapping=aes(x=household_income))
```

but the result is

[image: Income Distribution for Females with the wrong x-axis order]

I want a result like this

[image: Income Distribution for Females with the right x-axis order]

Comment: Hi Shkileo, can you add some of your data for Income Distribution? I suspect its type is of character which does not go well with plots.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Order Bars in ggplot2 bar graph](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5208679/order-bars-in-ggplot2-bar-graph)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Change the order of a discrete x scale](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3253641/change-the-order-of-a-discrete-x-scale)

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for comments, I found the way to solve it in a similar question.

```
positions = c("$0 - $24,999", "$25,000 - $49,999", "$50,000 - $99,999","$100,000 - $149,999")

ggplot(female_income)+geom_bar(mapping=aes(x=household_income))+scale_x_discrete(limits = positions)
```