# How do I order my ggplot x-axis in the descending order of the dataframe?

Tags: r, ggplot2

My dataframe column for the x-axis values is in the correct decreasing order that I want it, but the ggplot x-axis is rearranging the values according to alphabetical order. Basically, my x-axis variable contains a "Baseline" value, a range of treatment days "TD1, TD2, ..." values that are a different quantity for each subject, and a "Post" value.

Currently, ggplot reorders this alphabetically as 'Baseline, Post, TDx...', when clearly I need it to just follow the order of the dataframe.

How do I solve this? Can I do it in ggplot syntax, or is there a way to set the order of the variable before I pass the dataframe to ggplot? I cannot seem to find an answer that works.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Any time I see questions about `ggplot2` and *"order facets"*, almost every answer comes down to `factor`.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried ordering the factor that you are plotting on the x-axis before you plot the graph?

e.g. 
`x_axis$conditions <- factor(x_axis$conditions, levels = c("Baseline", "TD1", "TD2"))`

There are other answers on a similar question here: [Change the order of a discrete x scale](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3253641/change-the-order-of-a-discrete-x-scale)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to order in decreasing order, something like this should work:

```
p1 <- ggplot(data, aes(x=reorder(foo, -bar), y=bar))) +
    geom_bar(stat='identity')
```

If you need further clarification, please post a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example). You can manually set the order by changing the levels of the `factor`, also.