# GGplot reverse the boxplot sequence

Tags: r, ggplot2, reverse, boxplot

How can I reverse the order of Boxplot. In the picture you can see that 'After' is shown ahead of 'Before'. I want to reverse the order.
[image]

Comment: Could you please share a sample of your data and the code used for that plot in order to help you??

Comment: I'd suggest looking at the `forcats` package in this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3253641/order-discrete-x-scale-by-frequency-value

Comment: I think @LRRR's comment is the hint you need: order of `factor`s is almost always the solution to "order of" questions using `ggplot2`. If you still need help, it will be very useful for you to make this question reproducible. This includes sample code you've attempted (including listing non-base R packages, and any errors/warnings received), sample *unambiguous* data (e.g., `dput(head(x))` or `data.frame(x=...,y=...)`), and intended output given that input. Refs: https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269, [mcve], and https://stackoverflow.com/tags/r/info.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `fct_rev` for reversing the order of a factor or `fct_relevel` for changing the order manually.

Here is an example df.

```
df <- data.frame(values = rnorm(n = 300, mean = 50, sd = 15),
                 time = factor(rep(c(30, 40, 50), 100)),
                 situation = rep(c("Before", "After"), each = 150))
```

And here a example codes for the problem.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(forcats)

ggplot(df) +
  geom_boxplot(aes(x = time, 
                   y = values, 
                   color = fct_rev(situation))) +
  guides(color = guide_legend(title = "situation"))


ggplot(df) +
  geom_boxplot(aes(x = time, 
                   y = values, 
                   color = fct_relevel(situation, "After", after = 1))) +
  guides(color = guide_legend(title = "situation"))
```

Both codes result in this plot.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can also align the factors then draw the plot.

```
df$Situation <- factor(df$Situation, levels = c("Before", "After"))
```