# Order columns in geom_bar in ggplot in R

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to order my ggplot columns on a descending order but the code isn't working properly.

Here's the code:

```
Consolidado_novo %>%
 ggplot(aes(reorder(categoria, pesquisa_mensal), pesquisa_mensal)) + 
 geom_col(aes(x=categoria, y=pesquisa_mensal), fill="orange") + 
 labs(x = "Categorias",
   y = "Volume Mensal Pesquisas",
   title = "Análise KW Cosméticos")
```

Tha graph:[image: Graph]

The dataset:

|  | Keywords | categoria | Currency | pesquisa_mensal | mudanca_3meses |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | oxibenzona protetor solar | Protetor Solar | BRL | 90 | -57% |
| 2 | protetor solar com oxibenzona | Protetor Solar | BRL | 30 | 25% |
| 3 | quais protetores solares tem oxibenzona | Protetor Solar | BRL | 20 | 100% |
| 4 | avobenzona protetor solar | Protetor Solar | BRL | 20 | -67% |
| 5 | protetor solar sem oxibenzona | Protetor Solar | BRL | 110 | 0% |

Any hints?

Comment: Welcome - try to be more specific than 'code isn't working properly' - what exactly isn't working properly? Thank you.

Comment: I think every question on SO and elsewhere that references ggplot2 and "order of" something is resolved with the use of `factor(.., levels=..)`.

Comment: But this question doesn't appear to be reproducible, as the sample data and code produce (for me) a single column of `Protetor Solar`. It helps immensely if the sample data actually demonstrates the variability you intend. Can you update your data to include at least one more `categoria`, and where the default order is counter to what you intend?

Comment: My best guess is that you shouldn't specify `x =` two times in different ways. Keep the one with `reorder`, delete `x=categoria`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Order discrete x scale by frequency/value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3253641/order-discrete-x-scale-by-frequency-value)

Answer (score 0):

See `forcats::fct_reorder`.

The example provided is not reproducible, but this should do the trick:

```r
df <- data.frame(categoria = LETTERS[1:5],
                 pesquisa_mensal = c(20,100,110,90,50))

library(tidyverse)
df %>%
    mutate(categoria = fct_reorder(categoria, pesquisa_mensal, .desc = TRUE)) %>%
    ggplot(aes(categoria, pesquisa_mensal)) +
    geom_col()
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-11-29 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: i've got this error: Error: Problem with `mutate()` column `categoria`.
i `categoria = fct_reorder(categoria, pesquisa_mensal, .desc = TRUE)`.
x need numeric data

Comment: Is `pesquisa_mensal` not numeric?

Comment: THe variable pesquisa_mensal is numeric! But the variable categoria is not numeric, is a chr variable.

Comment: Then this should work. See the reproducible example posted above