# Reordering by x bar using one value of facet variable

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet-wrap

For the dataset below, I'd like to customize my below plot by ordering states according to the total number of deaths experienced by age 65. I tried the below code.

The answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3253641/order-discrete-x-scale-by-frequency-value) does not answer my question because my x variables include 50 values whereas the response is helpful for variables with a few values.

Thanks,

NM

Here is my data:

```
CAPS_2019 <- structure(list(Age = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 
2L, 3L), .Label = c("30", "50", "65"), class = "factor"), Dx = c(3.057, 
7.847, 17.157, 2.851, 8.861, 21.885, 2.521, 7.889, 21.328), PopName = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("AK", "AL", "AR"), class = "factor")), row.names = c(NA, 
-9L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

My code:

```
CAPS_plot_facet <- CAPS_2019 %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = reorder(PopName, Dx), y = Dx, fill = factor(as.character(Age)))) +
  geom_col(position = position_stack(reverse = TRUE)) +
  facet_wrap("Age",scales="free_x")+
  theme_classic()+
  theme(strip.background = element_blank(), strip.text = element_blank())+
  coord_flip()+
  labs(x = "State", y = "Deaths (%)", caption = (""), face = "bold", fill = "Age")
CAPS_plot_facet
```

My plot:

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Order discrete x scale by frequency/value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3253641/order-discrete-x-scale-by-frequency-value)

Comment: I don't think so! My x variables include 50 values whereas the response you are pointing to is helpful for variables with a few values.

Comment: I beg to differ.  You have more work to do because you have more levels of your "factor".  But I believe it gives you exactly the technique you need to use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@RobertoT's answer discusses how to sort by Age and Dx. If you want to do that inline using `dplyr::arrange` and `forcats::fct_inorder`:

**Reorder by Age and Dx**

```
library(dplyr)
library(forcats)

CAPS_2019 %>% 
  arrange(desc(Age), desc(Dx)) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = fct_inorder(PopName), y = Dx, fill = factor(as.character(Age)))) +
  geom_col(position = position_stack(reverse = TRUE)) +
  facet_wrap("Age",scales="free_x")+
  theme_classic()+
  theme(strip.background = element_blank(), strip.text = element_blank())+
  coord_flip()+
  labs(x = "State", y = "Deaths (%)", caption = (""), face = "bold", fill = "Age")
```

**Reorder specifically by Dx at Age 65**

If you want to specifically sort by Deaths for Age 65 (per the submission's question), you can do the following:

```
library(dplyr)
library(forcats)

CAPS_2019 %>% 
  group_by(PopName) %>%
  mutate(Dx_Age65 = Dx[Age == 65]) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = fct_reorder(PopName, Dx_Age65, .desc = TRUE), y = Dx, fill = factor(as.character(Age)))) +
  geom_col(position = position_stack(reverse = TRUE)) +
  facet_wrap("Age",scales="free_x")+
  theme_classic()+
  theme(strip.background = element_blank(), strip.text = element_blank())+
  coord_flip()+
  labs(x = "State", y = "Deaths (%)", caption = (""), face = "bold", fill = "Age")
```

Answer (score 1):

`Popname` is a factor with some levels that already sort the values. You have to rearrange them:

```
> CAPS_2019$PopName
[1] AK AK AK AL AL AL AR AR AR
Levels: AK AL AR
```

You can arrange the df by descending order in `Age` and `Dx` so the first values in `Popname` are sorted.

```
CAPS_2019 %>% arrange(desc(Age),desc(Dx))

# A tibble: 9 x 3
  Age      Dx PopName
  <fct> <dbl> <fct>  
1 65    21.9  AL     
2 65    21.3  AR     
3 65    17.2  AK     
4 50     8.86 AL     
5 50     7.89 AR     
6 50     7.85 AK     
7 30     3.06 AK     
8 30     2.85 AL     
9 30     2.52 AR
```

If you extract the unique values of `Popname` already sorted you can use them to reset the levels as you want. But, because you are using `coord_flip()` to flip the axis, the levels will be sorted the other way round in your plot. You can fix it in the ggplot code or just sort the levels in ascending order:

```
CAPS_2019 %>% arrange(desc(Age),Dx) %>% pull(PopName) %>% unique() %>% as.character()
[1] "AK" "AR" "AL"
```

Then, just edit the `Popname` column with the new levels:

```
CAPS_2019$PopName = factor(as.character(CAPS_2019$PopName), # the values
                           CAPS_2019 %>% arrange(desc(Age),Dx) %>% pull(PopName) %>% unique() %>% as.character()  # the levels sorted in ascending
)
[1] AK AK AK AL AL AL AR AR AR
Levels: AK AR AL
```

Next, plot the graph as it is. Changing the aesthetic for x-axis in `ggplot()` as: `x = Popname`

[image]

PS: Note if you don't flip the axis then the plot are sorted in ascending.

[image]

Comment: Thanks! This is really helpful! How can I sort y ascendingly? I tried y=-Dx but it changed the alignment of the bars.

Comment: Look my edit. I realised that `coord_flip()` change the order of the levels upside down.

Comment: @RobertoT and what is the difference to the provided code of the OP. It gives exactly the same plot. Or do I overlook something?

Comment: @TarJae In the previous code the x-axis is sorted with `x = reorder(PopName, Dx)`. This reorder the x-axis by total Dx among all Age categories. In my solution, the levels of PopName were sorted based only on Age == 65. It is just a coincidence that the order is the same in the example.  The previous code it is like reordering using: `CAPS_2019 %>% group_by(PopName) %>% summarise(Dx=sum(Dx)) %>% arrange(Dx)` which for sure won't be the same for a big df.

Comment: Actually, it will be much cleaner applying only `x = reorder(PopName, Z)`, where Z is only the order using AGE == 65. However, I don't know how.