# Sorting Ggplot columns

Tags: r, sorting, ggplot2

Im trying to make a ggplot of a factor column and I want the plot to start from decreasing order of the highest count. I sorted my data before I plotted, but I still get the plot like this. Could someone please let me know how I can get a cleaner plot?[image]

```
library(viridis)
library(ggplot2)
library(tidyverse)

phenotype <- data.frame (table(tiering$Phenotype))
phenotype <- phenotype %>% rename(Phenotype = Varl, Total = Freg)
phenotype <- phenotype[order(phenotype$Total, decreasing = TRUE) ,]
P <- ggplot(phenotype, aes(Phenotype, Total, fill = Total)) + geom_col() + geom_text(aes(label = Total), vjust= +0.3, size = 3.5) + theme classic() + ggtitle("Main phenotypes stated") +
scale_fill_viridis(option = "viridis")
```

[image]

Comment: Need to sort the `levels` attribute of the particular column. Sorting the integers in factors or sorting dataframe rownames are basically a meaningless processes

Comment: The phenotype column has 86 levels and the Total column has none. How do I sort it in such a way that the Total column order is plotted?

Comment: Hi Andy, I did try that solution before I posted on here. The aes(factor(Phenotype) was something I tried and it didn't work for me. Which is why I made the data frame again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a very quick way of doing it (where multiple solutions exist). Use `factor` to turn Phenotype into a factor and `forcats::fct_inorder` to arrange by the order you've already put them in.

On generated data:

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(viridis)
#> Loading required package: viridisLite

tibble(Phenotype = sample(50:99, 50, replace = FALSE),
       Total = exp(rpois(50, 3))) |> 
  arrange(desc(Total)) |> 
  ggplot(aes(fct_inorder(factor(Phenotype)), Total, fill = Total)) +
  geom_col() + 
  theme_classic() + 
  ggtitle("Main phenotypes stated") +
  scale_fill_viridis(option = "viridis")
```

[image]

Your question will perhaps be marked as a duplicate of [Order discrete x scale by frequency/value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3253641/order-discrete-x-scale-by-frequency-value) asked 12 years ago - which posits quite a few ways of getting the outcome you need. Found [by searching SO for `ggplot2` tag](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bggplot2%5D+order+x+axis)

You can also arrange your columns *within* the `ggplot(aes())` call with `fct_reorder(factor(Phenotype), ...)` like so:

```r
phenotype |>
  ggplot(aes(fct_reorder(factor(Phenotype), Total, .desc = TRUE), Total, fill = Total)) +
  geom_col()
```

Comment: HI, thank you for taking the time to provide a solution. I did try the questions you have alluded to in your answer, I couldn't fix mine. I tried your code and I got an error which said : "Error in fortify()"

Comment: I'm afraid I can't replicate the `fortify` error, as I cant see any place where it might be called in the code example! You may have to try updating `ggplot2` and restarting a fresh R session maybe?

Comment: I did exactly that and it worked. Thank you so much for you time and effort.